# Python I/O and string matching

Tags: python, io, string-matching

I realize this is probably really easy, I want the equivalent of this C code in Python:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUFFER 200
int main()
{
    char buffer[BUFFER];
    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFER, stdin))
    {
        if (strstr(buffer, "BEER"))
            printf("Drink up!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I searched on the web, but I think my brain is fried.

Comment: how equivalent do you want it?

Comment: I guess functionally equivalent, don't need character arrays or buffer limits.

Comment: The point is that this isn't a very Pythonic thing to do; normally you just do something like `for line in fileinput.fileinput():` and do stuff with each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent way of doing it, though not exactly the same

```
for line in iter(raw_input, ''):
    if 'BEER' in line:
        print('Drink up!')


foo
bar
aBEERc
Drink up!
***blank line***
```

---

Comment: Changed this to accepted answer - works better in the specific environment.

Answer (score 2):

The Pythonic thing to do is a little different:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    if "BEER" in line:
        print("Drink up!")
```

But that does a whole lot of things your C code doesn't do, like allowing the user to pass filename arguments to be read in place of stdin as arguments, etc.

---

This is a more direct mapping of your code:

```
try:
    while True:
        buffer = input() # or raw_input, for 2.x
        if "BEER" in buffer:
            print("Drink up!")
except EOFError:
    pass
```

However, it's missing the part where a line more than 300-character line that includes `"BEER"` in the first 200 characters and then again in the next will print twice, or a 300-character line that has "BEER" starting at position 198 won't print it at all.

---

If that's a problem, you probably want something like this:

```
import sys

while True:
    buffer = sys.stdin.readlines(200)
    if not buffer:
        break
    for line in buffer:
        for i in range(0, len(buffer), 200):
            if "BEER" in buffer[i*200:i*200+200]:
                print("Drink up!")
```

Comment: @cmd: I edited the answer to fix that, but then… `input()` raises an EOFError, so it _does_ terminate on EOF.

Comment: Thank you, I'll go with the most Pythonic method. I see other answers as well, Python is too TIMTOWTDI for me!

Comment: @YiminRong: Remember, it's not "There's only one way to do it", but "There's only one _obvious_ way to do it." If you want to make your life more difficult, you always can. Plus, you have to know what the "it" is before you can find the one way to do it. And if the "it" is "exactly what this C code does", you're often asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at `raw_input` for getting user input from stdin, and `print` for printing it to stdout:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print